# Kafka Streams - Integral versus Separable handler for flatMapValues

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I would like help deciding one of two paths I can follow from those more experienced with Kafka Streams in JAVA. I have two working JAVA apps that can take an inbound stream of integers and perform various calculations and tasks, creating four resultant outbound streams to different topics. The actual calc/tasks is not important, I am concerned
with the two possible methods I could use to define the handler that performs the math and any associated risks with my favorite.

**Method 1** uses a separately defined function that is of type ***Iterable*** and returns a ***List*** type.

**Method 2** uses the more common integral method that places the function within the ***KStream*** declaration.

I am very new to Kafka Streams and do not want to head down the wrong path. I like Method 1 because the code is very readable, easy to follow, and can have the handlers tested offline without needing to invoke traffic with streams.

Method 2 seems more common, but as the complexity grows, the code gets polluted in main(). Additionally I am boxed-in to testing algorithms using stream traffic, which slows development.

### Method 1: Separable handlers (partial):

```js
// Take inbound stream from math-input and perform transformations A-D, then write out to 4 streams.
KStream<String, String> source = src_builder.stream("math-input");
source.flatMapValues(value ->  transformInput_A(Arrays.asList(value.split("\\W+")))  ).to("math-output-A");
source.flatMapValues(value ->  transformInput_B(Arrays.asList(value.split("\\W+")))  ).to("math-output-B");
source.flatMapValues(value ->  transformInput_C(Arrays.asList(value.split("\\W+")))  ).to("math-output-C");
source.flatMapValues(value ->  transformInput_D(Arrays.asList(value.split("\\W+")))  ).to("math-output-D");

// More code here, removed for brevity.

// Transformation handlers A, B, C, and D.
// ******************************************************************
// Perform data transformation using method A
  public static Iterable transformInput_A (List str_array) {
       
       // Imagine some very complex math here using the integer
       // values. This could be 50+ lines of code.
      
       for (int i = 0; i < str_array.size(); i++) {
         // grab values and perform ops
       }

      // Return results in string format
      return math_results;
    }

// End of Transformation Method A
// ******************************************************************
// Imagine similar handlers for methods B, C, and D below.
```

### Method 2: Handlers internal to KStream declaration (partial):

```js
 // Take inbound stream from math-input and perform transformations A-D, then write out to 4 streams.
  KStream<String, String> inputStream = src_builder.stream("math-input");
  KStream<String, String> outputStream_A = inputStream.mapValues(new ValueMapper<String, String>() {
     @Override
     public String apply(String s) {

       // Imagine some very complex math here using the integer
       // values. This could be 50+ lines of code.

       for (int i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
         // grab values and perform ops
       }

       // Return results in Iterbale string format
       return math_results;
     }
  });


  // Send the data to the outbound topic A.
  outputStream_A.to("math-output-A");

  KStream<String, String> outputStream_B ....
  // Use ValueMapper in the KStream declaration just like above. 50+ lines of code
  outputStream_B.to("math-output-B");

  KStream<String, String> outputStream_C ....
  // Use ValueMapper in the KStream declaration just like above. 50+ lines of code
  outputStream_C.to("math-output-C");

  KStream<String, String> outputStream_D ....
  // Use ValueMapper in the KStream declaration just like above. 50+ lines of code
  outputStream_D.to("math-output-D");
```

Other than my desire to keep main() neat and push the complexity out of view, am I heading in the wrong direction with Method 1?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. Also, why do you use `flatMapValues()` in the first example, but `mapValues()` in the second example?

Comment: 1) Why two different calls: I was following documented examples. Those without an "apply()"  method used flatMapValues. Those that invoked "apply()" used mapValues with a new ValueMapper declaration. 2) Genesis of the question: Am I incurring risk of memory overflow, stack issues, et cetera with a separate handler?

Comment: Both, `mapValuee()` and `flatMapValuee()` take a `ValueMapper` and both will call `ValueMapper#apply()`. So I still cannot follow what you are saying. The difference is, that `mapValues()` is a 1:1 operator, meaning for each input record there will be exactly one output record. `flatMapValues()` is a 1:n operator though, thus each input record can result 0,1, or more output records. It's semantically two different things. Also, in both example you have the same number of handlers. If you call `value -> transformInput_A()`, this is just syntactic sugar for `new ValueMapper() {...}`.